# Index a large collection of MongoDB with Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose

I have a large collection (~25M) in MongoDB and I want to index all documents in it with ElasticSearch.

In my NodeJS with mongoose code, I am doing the following:

```
thebody = [];

Model
    .find({})
    .stream()
    .on('data', function(doc){
        thebody.push({index: {_index: index, _type: type, _id: doc._id}});
        thebody.push(doc);
    })
    .on('close', function () {
        client.bulk({
            body: thebody
        });
    })
```

I use the `bulk` function because I think that it is better than indexing each document individually. However, this leads to a memory problem (because of the large array `thebody`).

Is it better to index each element individually? Anyone know a better solution? (I can't use rivers because my ES version is 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

`Bulk API` is definitely faster and more efficient way if you are indexing huge amount of data.

However, the amount of data you will be able to successfully process will also depend upon the client's configuration. You definitely will not want to hold on to a large chunk of client resources.

Why not call `.bulk` function in batches of say 10k documents.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose that this is my option. But is the only way to index large collections in ES? I am surprised no other options like the rivers driver, or similar ways than Sphinx or Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoosastic :https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic/blob/master/README.md

Mongoosastic is a mongoose plugin that can automatically index your models into elasticsearch.
The latest version of this package will be as close as possible to the latest elasticsearch and mongoose packages.

npm install -S mongoosastic